# how to add second table in sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have database comments.db I already created one table table_comments and now
I want to create second table (table_birthday) in this database. My question is how do I add this table in the existing database? I have following code. Any help appreciated.

```
package com.example.proj1;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //table 1
    public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
      public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";

      //table 2
      public static final String TABLE_BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
      public static final String Birthday_ID = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_Birthday = "bday";

      //database
      private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

      // table 1
      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
          + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
          + " text not null);";

      //table 2
      private static final String DATABASE_CREAT = "create table "
              + TABLE_BIRTHDAY + "(" + Birthday_ID
              + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_Birthday
              + " text not null);";


      public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
          }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREAT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COMMENTS);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_BIRTHDAY);
            onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

Comment: This code should be doing it... What's the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804083/how-to-add-second-table-in-database-in-sqlite

this problem is already solve just see the link

Answer (score 2):

Either wipe your application data using the app manager, or just uninstall and reinstall your app.

Your test environment already has a database with schema version 1 and when you modified the schema by adding another table, the database is not upgraded nor created since the schema versions are the same and the database already exists.

For released versions you should instead bump up `DB_VERSION` and implement corresponding migration code in `onUpgrade()`.