# How to add second table with one database in sql ite in android,data not inserted in second table

Tags: android

Here is my code.

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String create="create table "+TABLE_NAME+"("+FIELD1+"  integer primary key  autoincrement, "+FIELD2+" Text, "+FIELD3+" Text )";
        String createone="create table "+TABLE_USERS+"("+KEY_FNAME+" Text, "+KEY_LNAME+" Text)";  
        db.execSQL(create);
        db.execSQL(createone);

        public void add(String fnm,String lnm)
        {
         SQLiteDatabase dbone=this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues cvone=new ContentValues();
         cvone.put(KEY_FNAME, fnm);
         cvone.put(KEY_LNAME, lnm);
         dbone.insert(TABLE_USERS, null,cvone);
        }
```

Comment: Add a second `CREATE TABLE` statement. Then increase the `DATABASE_VERSION` value.

Comment: when you want to add new table..??

Comment: please send code to add.with Oncreate method.i was also do but it's not work successfully

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add second table in database in sqlite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804083/how-to-add-second-table-in-database-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 1):

I have do like this..
change field as per your requirement.

```
public void createTable (String tableName) {

final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
String TABLE_NEW_CONVERSATION = tableName;

String CREATE_TABLE_NEW_CONVERSATION = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NEW_CONVERSATION +
        " (" + CONVERSATION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        CONVERSATION_MESSAGE + " TEXT," +
        CONVERSATION_ISDELIVERED + " TEXT," +
        CONVERSATION_TIME + " TEXT," +
        CONVERSATION_DATE + " TEXT," +
        CONVERSATION_PATH + " TEXT," +
        CONVERSATION_FROM + " TEXT )";

db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NEW_CONVERSATION);
db.close();
```

}

Comment: Is it compulsory to close database?

Comment: how you get .db file from device..??

Comment: we are working in Eclipse IDE.So we are using SQLite DB Browser.For show the table data.

Comment: You can also pull the sqlite db file right off your device (or emulator) by going into the DDMS perspective in Eclipse (Window menu\ Open perspective \ Other \ DDMS), navigating to the database file which will probably be at \data\data\*Your Application Name*\databases.

There's a 'pull file' button on the top left as seen highlighted below:

Comment: I know that..!! now how you call this function..??

Comment: i m not understand what you ask?

Comment: how you call this function createTable (talename);...??? i mean in any activity..??

Comment: // My Oncreate method-public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String create="create table "+TABLE_NAME+"("+FIELD1+"  integer primary key  autoincrement, "+FIELD2+" Text, "+FIELD3+" Text )";
  String createone="create table "+TABLE_USERS+"("+KEY_FNAME+" Text, "+KEY_LNAME+" Text)";  
  db.execSQL(create);
  db.execSQL(createone);

Comment: //onUpgrade method public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
             // Simplest implementation is to drop all old tables and recreate them
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
             onCreate(db);
 
   }

Comment: please use pastebin.com

Comment: Thanks Nils For Helping

Comment: public void add(String fnm,String lnm)
 {
  SQLiteDatabase dbone=this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues cvone=new ContentValues();
  cvone.put(KEY_FNAME, fnm);
  cvone.put(KEY_LNAME, lnm);
  dbone.insert(TABLE_USERS, null,cvone);
 }// code for insert data

Comment: what is it?i don't understand

Comment: your code will look fine for other, so we can understand very well your code.

Comment: i can. First upload your code in proper format, code in comments..how i understand??? i tell u post your code in www.pastie.org so i check it properly.

Comment: ok....now press button "create past" and when its show new page, copy url of page and send me.

Comment: sorry i cannot more help like this way. i need full code.

Answer (score 0):

To add another table to an already existing database, modify your `onUpgrade` method. `onUpgrade is called whenever the database needs to be upgraded; note that you must increment the VERSION_NUMBER (which you will want to include as a private instance variable in your class)

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.executeSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);
}
```

now DATABASE_CREATE2 is

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 = "create table IF NOT EXISTS "
+ TABLE_CHAPTER + "( " + COLUMN_ID
+ " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
+ COLUMN_SUBJECT + " text not null, "
+ COLUMN_CHAPTER + " text, "
+ COLUMN_QUESTION + " text not null,"
+ COLUMN_OPTIONA + " text not null,"
+ COLUMN_OPTIONB + " text not null,"
+ COLUMN_OPTIONC + " text not null,"
+ COLUMN_OPTIOND + " text not null,"
+ COLUMN_CORRECT + " text not null,"
+ COLUMN_CONFIRM + " text not null);";
```

Comment: what means by another method?